# How to export Environment variables from .sh file in windows?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am working on a Java project that was written in MAC OS. There .sh file contains environment variables that are database user names and passwords. 
When i imported this project into my windows machine, these variables are not being read.

below is the code for karate-test.env file

```
env=test

export KARATE_MYSQL_USER=dbusername

pass=oldpass

if [ $env == "stage" ]; then

pass=newpassword



fi

export KARATE_MYSQL_PASS=%pass
```

These file is read by another karate-config.js file.

```
function() {


var env = karate.env; 


var dbUser = java.lang.System.getenv("KARATE_MYSQL_USER");


var dbPassword = java.lang.System.getenv("KARATE_MYSQL_PASS");
```

When i run my code, i get db connection not made error.

What changes are necessary to make sure these environment files are being exported properly.

Comment: what OS are you using for this? setting environment vars varies quite a bit by the OS concerned ... [*grin*]

Comment: im on windows 10, this project was developed in mac os

Comment: you will need to document exactly what the `.sh` file actually does. then parse it. then use `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` to make the setting stick OR just use the info directly without fooling with the environment at all. ///// alternately, you can enable the Windows System for Linux and then use the `.sh` file directly.

Comment: I'm using the environment variables to just store myswl db username and password.
currently in mac os variables are written as --- export VEHICLE_API_PASS=Test@4239
If i need to declare these same variables in windows os, how would i do it, this was the question i meant to ask

Comment: the way to set an env. var. so that it shows for other processes is to use what i listed above - >>> `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` <<< that will let you set things for the machine, the user, or the process. you likely want to set that for the user - but i would carefully test that & use the narrowest that will work in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I used a batch file to set these variables.

of 'export', i used 'set'

@ECHO OFF

set env=stage

set  KARATE_MYSQL_USER=someuser

set  KARATE_MYSQL_PASS=somepasskey

This seems to be working fine for me.

Thank you for the replies..

Answer (score 0):

If such a file looks something like this:

```
export KARATE_MYSQL_USER=KarateUser
export KARATE_MYSQL_PASS=Karate@89272363
export VEHICLE_API_PASS=Test@4239
```

Then parsing it like below should work for you:

```
$envFile = 'X:\variables.env'
$content = Get-Content -Path $envFile -Raw  # read the file as single string

$regex = [regex] '(?im)export\s+(?<varname>[^=]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.+)$'
$match = $regex.Match($content)
while ($match.Success) {
    $varName  = $match.Groups['varname'].Value
    $varValue = $match.Groups['value'].Value
    Write-Host "Setting Environment variable '$varName' to '$varValue'"
    # set the environment variable in Windows.
    # If this does needs to apply to ALL users, use 'Machine' instead of 'User'
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($varName, $varValue, 'User') 
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

Regex details:

```
export            Match the characters “export” literally
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “varname”
   [^=]           Match any character that is NOT a “=”
      +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
=                 Match the character “=” literally
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?         Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “value”
   .              Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                
$                 Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

<sup>the `(?im)` makes the regex case-insensitive and lets `^` and `$` match at line breaks</sup>